# Dell Drivers for Inspiron N4050

Tags: windows-7, drivers, fedora, dell-inspiron, wifi-driver

I have to say this: this is the first time I ever find difficulty in installing device drivers. I fresh-installed Windows 7 Pro 64-bit with absolutely no drivers or programs installed.

I tried everything, searched forums, looked at the Dell support sites and downloaded some drivers from there, and downloaded the N4050 drivers CD iso, but nothing worked. This is so frustrating that I don't even know what to try next.

[Here is the support page for my Laptop](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-14-intel-n4050/drivers)

Which wifi driver should I download? There are several different ones.

Thanks in advance.

#### Edit:

I found most of the drivers needed except for the Wireless and Bluetooth drivers. The wireless card in my laptop (according to the service tag page) is an Atheros DELL WIRELESS 1702 802. I tried installing [the specified driver](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=TRJHK) but the installer output an error:

> *Title:* 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless Adapter Device Not Found
> *Message:* The Device may not be present or could have been ejected/unplugged from the System. Insert or Reinsert Now.

What should I do ?

Comment: @Moab: I did, and nothing worked.

Comment: You need to provide links to specific drivers you have tried and explain in detail what went wrong when installing them, otherwise this question may be closed as "unclear what you are asking". I have used Dell drivers on Dell PC's for over 15 years without issue, we need more detail so we can help you figure out what is going on. Including how good Fedora worked does not help us at all when diagnosing Windows driver issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys, I found the solution.

I connected my laptop to an android device that is connected to the internet and shared the connection using [usb tethering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethering), so now I established an internet connection.

Then, I used [Driver Easy](https://www.drivereasy.com/) to update existing and install missing drivers. Surprisingly enough, this actually worked !

Answer (score 0):

It will difficult to find "N4050 drivers CD iso" as you mentioned. But still you can try [Dell System Detect](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Home/Index/QuickTest) or [Dell System Software Utility](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=JX1KK) to analyze your system. Or you can use the online device detecting application provided by dell. You can find more information [here](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN117738/EN). Otherwise you can try other commercial driver detecting applications such like [Driver Detective](http://www.drivershq.com/), etc. Or probably if you know the driver information [dell site](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Products/?app=drivers) itself provide all the necessary device drivers.

Comment: The problem with these System Analyze utilities is that they need a working internet connection, and as I mentioned above, I couldn't get the WIFI drivers working. As for finding the CD iso, I found that on a torrenting site, and I guess it is legal to download drivers.

Comment: I'm not sure about torrents. [This page](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-14-intel-n4050/drivers) has the required drivers for your system. Enter your system "Service Tag". It will give you all the required drivers. You can try this using another PC.